# AngularJS filter is not working in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, cakephp-2.0

My AngularJS filter is not working with an Object.

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchKeyUser.$" placeholder="Pesquisar Chaves" class="form-control"><br>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item clicavel chaves" ng-repeat="chave in keyUsers | filter:searchKeyUser" ng-class="{ active:Grupo.isActiveKey(chave.Chave.id)}" ng-click="Grupo.mostrar()">
          {{chave.Chave.chave}}{{chave.show}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to use searchKeyUser.$, searchKeyUser.Chave.$, searchKeyUser.Chave.chave, and nothing happened. Detail: the text `{{chave.Chave.chave}}{{chave.show}}` is working.

EDIT:
Js code:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('groupUsers', []);
  app.controller('GroupsController', function($scope, $http){

    //Busca rel Chaves Usuarios
    $http.get(myBaseUrl + '/QlikRelKeyUser/retornoGroups').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.keyUsers = data;
      console.log($scope.keyUsers);
      for(x in $scope.keyUsers){
        aux = 0;
        qtd = $scope.keyUsers[x].QlikUser.length;
        for(y in $scope.keyUsers[x].QlikUser){
          aux++;
          if(qtd == 1){
            $scope.keyUsers[x].show = ' (' + $scope.keyUsers[x].QlikUser[y].nome + ')';
          }else if(aux == qtd){
            $scope.keyUsers[x].show += ', ' + $scope.keyUsers[x].QlikUser[y].nome + ')';
          }else{
            if(aux==1){
              $scope.keyUsers[x].show = ' (' + $scope.keyUsers[x].QlikUser[y].nome;
            }else{
              $scope.keyUsers[x].show += ', ' +       $scope.keyUsers[x].QlikUser[y].nome;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      console.log('');
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('NÃO FUNFOU');
      console.log(config);
    });
    $scope.searchKeyUser = {$:''};
   });
```

EDIT 2: 
Same View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchGroup.$" placeholder="Pesquisar Grupos" class="form-control"><br>
        <ul class="list-group" >
          <li class="list-group-item clicavel" ng-repeat="group in grupos | filter:searchGroup" ng-class="{ active:Grupo.isSet(group.QlikUserGroup.id)}" ng-click="Grupo.setActive(group.QlikUserGroup.id)">
            {{group.QlikUserGroup.nome}}
            <span class='badge bg-important'>1</span>
            <span class='badge' stylee='padding-right:30px;'>{{Grupo.totalKeys(group.QlikUserGroup.id)}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Same JS:

```
$http.get(myBaseUrl + '/QlikUserGroup/retornoGroups').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.grupos = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('NÃO FUNFOU');
      console.log(config);
    });
```

My `console.log($scope.grupos);` returns:

```
Array[67]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:530"
QlikUserGroup: Object
id: "1"
nome: "Name name name"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
...
```

Comment: provide your js code also. What _searchKeyUser_ ? What you try filter? by all field? or by some? or by one?

Comment: I first tried as it is right now

Comment: are you sure that `$scope.keyUsers` is array? seems it _object_

Comment: oh, really it's a object, i'm sorry

Comment: i'm using CakePHP framework to take the objects from database

Comment: _filter_ working **only** with array

Comment: But, my another "table" with filter is working normally, and the requisition returns an Object too, but in format: QlikUserGroup = array(id, nome);

Comment: CakePHP always returns an Object or an array of Objects

Comment: so show your _another "table"_, and  how it work, it woud be great if you can provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) also

Comment: I added the another "table"

Comment: I think that will be very difficult to provide jsfiddle or plunker becaus all in my project are connected

Comment: can you provide value for _data_ in `get(myBaseUrl + '/QlikUserGroup/retornoGroups')` and in `get(myBaseUrl + '/QlikRelKeyUser/retornoGroups')`?

Comment: also js **not** same, you do request to different url

Comment: it's the same js file, in the same scope

Comment: so, can you provide what json return each url?

Comment: I don't know how can I provide what json return, but I take from console.log()..

Comment: try do `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.grupos))` and `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.keyUsers))` it return more readable json

Comment: anyway i see that `$scope.grupos` is **array**, so all correct - filter working ok with array, what with `$scope.keyUsers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) working only with array, but you try pass *object*. So you have at least two solutions

- modify server side and return array
- make array from object in js, something like this

  ```
  $scope.keyUsers = [];
  console.log(data);
  for(x in data){
      var el = data[x];
      $scope.keyUsers.push(el);
      el.show = '('+ el.QlikUser.map(function(el){ return el.nome; }).join(', ') +')';
  }
  console.log($scope.keyUsers);
  ```

```js
var data = {
  '1': {
    'QlikUser': [{
      nome: 'a'
    }, {
      nome: 'b'
    }, {
      nome: 'c'
    }, {
      nome: 'd'
    }, ]
  }
}

var keyUsers = [];
console.log(data);
for (x in data) {
  var el = data[x];
  keyUsers.push(el);
  el.show = '(' + el.QlikUser.map(function(el) {
    return el.nome;
  }).join(', ') + ')';
}
console.log(keyUsers);
```

Comment: It works to convert the object of objects to array of objects, but the logic for `el.show = '('+ data[x].QlikUser.join(', ') +')';` doen't work because the QlikUser is an array :/ I tried to foud what happened and I modified my return code

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe, [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is a method from `Array.prototype` so if _QlikUser_ really is array it should work, but seems it also object with _length_ property :-)

Comment: but it is writing `([object Object])` in $scope.keyUser[x].show

Comment: because the structure of `QlikUser` is `QlikUser = array(array(id, name), array(id2, name2))` (array of arrays), like a `var QlikUser = [array(id, name), array(id2, name2)]`

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe, fix code sample and add snippet, try it